# For a smooth function having a positive definite hessian at all points, having a local minimum implies it is a global unique minimum

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$ and let $L: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have positive definite Hessian at all points. Then $\mathrm{L}$ having a local minimum implies it is a unique global minimum.

So I know the way we show that a critical point is a local minimum is by the multivariate Taylor series. But how can we show now that the local minimum is in fact global and unique? Do we still use the Taylor expansion for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use the univariate Taylor's theorem.

Let $x_0$ satisfy $\nabla L(x_0)=0$. Fix a direction $h \in V$. Define the univariate function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(t) = L(x_0 + th)$.

Note that $f'(t) = \langle \nabla L(x_0 + th), h\rangle$ and $f''(t) = \langle h,  (\nabla^2 L(x_0 + th))h\rangle$.
In particular,

- $f'(0) = 0$ because of the assumption $\nabla L(x_0) = 0$, and
- $f''(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ because $\nabla^2 L$ is positive definite everywhere by assumption.

Taylor's theorem implies
$$f(t) = f(0) + f'(0) t + \frac{f''(\xi_t)}{2} t^2$$
for some $\xi_t$ between $0$ and $t$. Plugging in the definition of $f$ and using the above two facts, we can rewrite the above as
$$L(x_0 + th) = L(x_0) + 0 + \frac{1}{2} \langle h, (\nabla^2 L(x_0 + \xi_t h)) h\rangle t^2 \ge L(x_0).$$

Since $h$ was arbitrary, we have $L(x) \ge L(x_0)$ for all $x$.

Comment: May I ask what is the notation here :  $f''(t) = \langle h,  (\nabla^2 L(x_0 + th))h\rangle$. What does the above mean?

Comment: @Bill $H:= \nabla^2 L(x_0 + th)$ is a matrix (the Hessian), and $h$ is a vector. The above notation denotes $h^\top H h$. In general you can replace $\langle a, b \rangle$ with $a^\top b$ if you prefer to use the transpose notation.

Comment: Thank you. Also is there an easy way to see the second derivative gives us  $\langle h,  (\nabla^2 L(x_0 + th))h\rangle$. Things got messy very fast when I tried writing it out.

Comment: @Bill Maybe revisit how the chain rule works for multivariate functions.

Comment: hi, i was wondering is it possible to extend the proof of this result to even conclude that L is coercive , that as h goes to infinity L(h) goes to infinity. The only thing that seems to be getting in the way of that conclusion is the fact that theta depends on t, so as t gets very large , its possible that theta varies in a way that shrinks just as fast.

Comment: @Bill It might be better to ask this as a separate question.